# Java Maze Solver (DFS)

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

I was asked to create a Java program that will navigate through a series of mazes. I would like to know if this is the optimal way of using a DFS or is there a better way and I am doing something wrong?

Example of a Maze File:

```
10 10
1 1
8 8
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

This file is then converted into a 2DInt array where 0 are empty spaces and 1 is a wall. The maze can wrap around itself too so you can go from one side to another if the space is 0 on either side. 10 10 is the maze size, 1 1 is starting location and 8 8 is ending location.

I have used the Depth-First-Search to solve this maze, here is the code:

MAIN CLASS

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.Queue;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Stack;



    public class Main {
    static Stack<Node> q = new Stack<Node>(); // Stack is used for Depth First Search Algorithm, Queue can be used to
                                                // convert DFS into a Breadth-first search algorithm.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter exact maze file location: ");
        String fileLocation = reader.nextLine();
        reader.close();

        ArrayList<String> mazeRaw = new ArrayList<String>();
        File file = new File(fileLocation);

        try {
            String st;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)
                mazeRaw.add(st);
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }

        Maze testMaze = new Maze(mazeRaw); //2D Int array maze constructor
        String[][] results = new String[testMaze.maze2D.length][testMaze.maze2D[0].length];
        Node p = solveMaze(testMaze, testMaze.returnStart()); //Node p contains p.parent that hold the path through the maze. 

        testMaze.printMazeResult(results, p, testMaze.returnStart()); 

    }

    public static Node solveMaze(Maze maze, Node start) {
        q.push(new Node(start.x, start.y, null)); // Adds the starting coordinates to the stack.
        while (!q.isEmpty()) // Until the stack is empty continue loop.
        {
            Node p = q.pop(); // Get the top element from the Stack and assign it to p

            // Valid States //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------// 

            //If Exit found at coordinates p.x,p.y in 2Dint Array return the p Node.
            if (maze.getMaze2D()[p.x][p.y] == 9) {
                return p;
            }

            //If x,y location cannot be wrapped on either ends then check if its sparse for formatting purposes. 
            if (!isWrappable(maze, p) && isSparse(maze, p)) {
                maze.getMaze2D()[p.x][p.y] = -1;
                Node nextP = new Node(p.x + 1, p.y, p);
                q.push(nextP);
                continue;
            }

            //Check if p node is at the border and if the border wraps around the array in a valid way and make sure that the node parent is not at border to avoid loops
            if (isWrappingBorder(maze, p.x, p.y, p) != null && isWrappingBorder(maze, p.parent.x, p.parent.y, p.parent) == null) {
                q.push(isWrappingBorder(maze, p.x, p.y, p));
            }

            // 4 Directional Movements //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

            // South
            if (isFree(maze, p.x + 1, p.y)) {
                maze.getMaze2D()[p.x][p.y] = -1;
                Node nextP = new Node(p.x + 1, p.y, p);
                q.push(nextP);
            }

            // North
            if (isFree(maze, p.x - 1, p.y)) {
                maze.getMaze2D()[p.x][p.y] = -1;
                Node nextP = new Node(p.x - 1, p.y, p);
                q.push(nextP);
            }

            // West
            if (isFree(maze, p.x, p.y + 1)) {
                maze.getMaze2D()[p.x][p.y] = -1;
                Node nextP = new Node(p.x, p.y + 1, p);
                q.push(nextP);
            }

            // East
            if (isFree(maze, p.x, p.y - 1)) {
                maze.getMaze2D()[p.x][p.y] = -1;
                Node nextP = new Node(p.x, p.y - 1, p);
                q.push(nextP);
            }
        }
        return null; // If Maze cannot be solved value null is returned;
    }

    //This method checks if the coordinates adjacent to the Node p are empty to detect sparse input for formatting purposes
    public static boolean isSparse(Maze maze, Node p) {
        if (maze.getMaze2D()[p.x][p.y - 1] == 0 && maze.getMaze2D()[p.x + 1][p.y] == 0
                && maze.getMaze2D()[p.x + 1][p.y - 1] == 0 || maze.getMaze2D()[p.x + 1][p.y] == 9)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    //Checks if the array can be wrapped around at either ends and direction from the current Node p.
    public static boolean isWrappable(Maze maze, Node p) {
        if (maze.getMaze2D()[0][p.y] == 0 || maze.getMaze2D()[p.x][0] == 0
                || maze.getMaze2D()[maze.getMaze2D().length - 1][p.y] == 0
                || maze.getMaze2D()[p.x][maze.getMaze2D()[0].length - 1] == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    //Detect the point where Array wraps around itself and return a Node that comes out on the other side of the wrapped array
    public static Node isWrappingBorder(Maze maze, int x, int y, Node parent) {
        Node nextNode;

        if (x == 0 && maze.getMaze2D()[x][y] != 1) {
            if (maze.getMaze2D()[maze.getMaze2D().length - 1][y] != 1)
                return nextNode = new Node(maze.getMaze2D().length - 1, y, parent);
        }

        if (x == maze.getMaze2D().length - 1 && maze.getMaze2D()[x][y] != 1) {
            if (maze.getMaze2D()[0][y] != 1)
                return nextNode = new Node(0, y, parent);
        }

        if (y == 0 && maze.getMaze2D()[x][y] != 1) {
            if (maze.getMaze2D()[x][maze.getMaze2D().length - 1] != 1)
                return nextNode = new Node(x, maze.getMaze2D().length - 1, parent);
        }

        if (y == maze.getMaze2D()[0].length - 1 && maze.getMaze2D()[x][y] != 1) {
            if (maze.getMaze2D()[x][0] != 1)
                return nextNode = new Node(x, 0, parent);
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Checks if int x, and int y which are passed from Node.x and Node.y values are valid coordinates
    public static boolean isFree(Maze maze, int x, int y) {
        if ((x >= 0 && x < maze.getMaze2D().length) && (y >= 0 && y < maze.getMaze2D()[x].length)
                && (maze.getMaze2D()[x][y] == 0 || maze.getMaze2D()[x][y] == 9))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

MAZE CLASS

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;


public class Maze {
    int[][] maze2D; //
    private Node start;         
    private Node end;

    public Maze(ArrayList<String> mazeString) {
        this.maze2D = new int[(Integer.valueOf(mazeString.get(0).split(" ")[1]))][(Integer
                .valueOf(mazeString.get(0).split(" ")[0]))]; // Assign maze size from the file.
        start = new Node(Integer.valueOf(mazeString.get(1).split(" ")[1]), Integer.valueOf(mazeString.get(1).split(" ")[0]), null);
        end = new Node(Integer.valueOf(mazeString.get(2).split(" ")[1]), Integer.valueOf(mazeString.get(2).split(" ")[0]), null);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.maze2D.length; i++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < this.maze2D[i].length; n++) {
                this.maze2D[i][n] = Integer.valueOf(mazeString.get(i + 3).split(" ")[n]); // i + 3 to offset first 3 lines of text file. 
            }
        }
        this.maze2D[start.x][start.y] = 8; // Assign maze start from the file.
        this.maze2D[end.x][end.y] = 9; // Assign maze end from the file.
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(this.maze2D));
        return (this.maze2D.toString());
    }

    public Node returnStart() 
    {
        return start;
    }

    public Node returnEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public int[][] getMaze2D() {
        return maze2D;
    }

    public void setMaze2D(int[][] maze2d) {
        maze2D = maze2d;
    }

    public void printMazeResult(String[][] results, Node p, Node start) {
        Boolean mazeState = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < getMaze2D().length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < getMaze2D()[i].length; j++) {
                switch (maze2D[i][j]) {
                case 0:
                    results[i][j] = " ";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    results[i][j] = "#";
                    break;
                case -1:
                    results[i][j] = " ";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    results[i][j] = "E";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            while (p.getParent() != null) {
                p = p.getParent();
                if (maze2D[p.x][p.y] == 9)
                    continue;
                results[p.x][p.y] = "X";
            }
            results[start.y][start.x] = "S";
            mazeState = true;
        } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
            mazeState = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < results[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(results[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        if (mazeState == true)
            System.out.println("- Maze has been solved :) -");
        else
            System.out.println("- Maze is unsolvable -");

    }

}
```

NODE CLASS

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Node 
{
      int x;
      int y;
      Node parent;

      public Node(int x, int y, Node parent) {
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.parent = parent;
      }

      public Node() {
          this.x = 0;
          this.y = 0;
          this.parent = null;
      }

      public Node getParent() {
          return this.parent;
      }

      public String toString() {
          return "x = " + x + " y = " + y;
      }







}
```

OUTPUT:

```
##########
XS#XXXXXXX
  #X######
# #XXXX  #
# ## #X###
# #  #X# #
# #  XX  #
# ###X####
# #  XXXE#
##########
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### API and Reusability

`solveMaze` takes both a `Maze maze` and `Node start`, even though `Maze` defines a `start` position already.

The use of the static `q` Stack means it is not reusable: if a solution is found, then it will remain populated, and interfere with the next run. You can also not reuse `Maze`s, because `solveMaze` replaces the empty spaces with `-1`: it would be much nicer if it did not modify the `Maze` it is given or, at the very least, reset the `Maze` once it has finished.

Given you don't use `q` outside of `solveMaze`, there is no sense in making it a member of the class, when it could be a local variable, created on demand. It would be nice to see the maze-solving logic in its own class, rather than mixed up with the calling code.

### Magic numbers

`0`, `9`, `8`, `-1`... these are all meaningless to anyone who might be trying to use your classes and methods without having first inspected your code. They are a maintainability concern, because changing a `9` in one place has no effect in any of the others, and a find-and-replace for `9` is a nightmare waiting to happen. Much better to use meaningful constant values:

```
public static final int EmptyCell = 0;
public static final int StartCell = 8;
public static final int EndCell = 9;
public static final int VisitedCell = -1;
```

You could also hide the implementation details as best as possible. `isFree`, for example, could be a member of `maze`. `setVisited` could be added as a member, so that you can do away with `maze.getMaze2D()[p.x][p.y] = -1;`.

### `try ... catch`

The `try ... catch` in `main` pretty much swallows any exception that might occur while reading the file, and then proceeds to allow the rest of the code to run, as though nothing has gone wrong. I'd prefer that this code printed the exception and stack-trace and then exited cleanly; otherwise, the code that follows after it is likely to fail on the invalid input it will receive, and the original source of the problem will be less apparent.

You should also close the `BufferedReader` in a `finally` block, to ensure this unmanaged resource is freed as soon as possible; or, better, use a try-with-resources statement, which make it difficult to misuse the `BufferedReader` (e.g. by forgetting to close it, or by using it when it has already been closed)

The `try ... catch` in `printMazeResult` is rather concerning: it seems that it's purpose is to deal with the case where `p` is `null` because `solveMaze` returned `null`. This, however, is wholly unclear from the code itself, and the `try ... catch` is liable to obscure bugs inside the code which are unrelated to whether the maze was or was note solved. You should use an explicit check to determine whether the maze was solved:

```
Boolean mazeIsSolved = p != null
```

(this is a better name than `mazeState`, which sounds like a transient concern)

### Wrapping

The 'wrapping' code looks needlessly complicated. I'd be strongly inclined to remove it completely, and instead perform 'wrapping' in the NESW checks (see below).

The wrapping code itself would be much nicer if `maze` exposed the width and height of the `maze`, as the code is currently dotted with `maze.getMaze2D()[maze.getMaze2D().length - 1]`, which is just a distraction from its real purpose. Many other places in the code would benefit from such methods also.

I don't think `isWrappingBorder` is a very good name, since it does a lot more than determine whether it is a wrapping border. It's comment (which would ideally be [JavaDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc)) also fails to mention that it will return `null` if it is not a wrapping Border. More importantly, I think it is deficient in the cases where you are against both borders, as it can only return a single value.

The `return nextNode = ...` theme is confusing: you assign a local variable only to return it immediately. There is no value in the local variable, and you can safely remove it.

### NESW movement

Your have basically the same piece of code here four times, just with a different `+/- 1`: put this in a method, so that there is one reusable version to maintain, and it is easier to follow the logic in `solveMaze` without worrying about the details. Something like this would work:

```
static void tryMove(Maze maze, Node p, Stack<Node> q, int dx, int dy) {
    // offset and wrap
    int x = (p.x + dx + maze.getWidth()) % maze.getWidth();
    int y = (p.x + dy + maze.getHeight()) % maze.getHeight();

    if (isFree(maze, x, y)) {
        maze.getMaze2D()[p.x][p.y] = -1;
        Node nextP = new Node(x, y, p);
        q.push(nextP);
    }
}
```

Using it is then just a case of:

```
tryMove(maze, p, q, -1, 0);
tryMove(maze, p, q, +1, 0);
tryMove(maze, p, q, 0, -1);
tryMove(maze, p, q, 0, +1);
```

The following line appears once for each direction; it should presumably be run even if no move can be made, and doesn't need to be run for each in turn.

```
maze.getMaze2D()[p.x][p.y] = -1;
```

### Naming

Your naming could be better. `q`, for example, is pretty meaningless. I guess that `Node p` stands for 'point'. It's also odd to see `x` and `y` as the `row` and `column` indices, rather than the other way round (e.g. normally the x-axis is east-west, not north-south).

In some places you use `i` and `j` as loop variables, in other `i` and `n`: `n` *usually* means a count, `j` is a better choice; however, `i` and `j` do not convey all that much; `(r)ow` and `(c)ol` would be more meaningful.

### `Maze` constructor

The parameter `ArrayList<String> mazeString` is not a `String`, but rather a collection of lines. You might also consider taking the abstract `List<String>`, rather than requiring the particular derived typed, so that your interface is easier to use.

The following is pretty unreadable, and the line-break is not in a very nice place:

```
this.maze2D = new int[(Integer.valueOf(mazeString.get(0).split(" ")[1]))][(Integer
    .valueOf(mazeString.get(0).split(" ")[0]))];
```

Instead of trying to squeeze all of that onto one line, break it up:

```
string[] dimensionData = mazeString.get(0).split(" ");
int width = Integer.valueOf(dimensionData[0]);
int height = Integer.valueOf(dimensionData[1]);

this.maze2D = new int[width][height];
```

Now it is instantly recognisable what the code is meant to do, and the details are laid out plainly, and without repetition (repeated code is a maintainability concern, as all instances have to kept consistent).

Performance shouldn't be an issue here, but little things like re-splitting whole lines of input for each entry should be avoided, as they can (as in this instance) turn a simple quadratic-complexity operation into a cubic cost, potentially creating problems in seemingly unlikely places:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.maze2D.length; i++) {
    String[] lineData = mazeString.get(i + 3).split(" "); // i + 3 to offset first 3 lines of text file.

    for (int j = 0; j < this.maze2D[i].length; j++) {
        this.maze2D[i][j] = Integer.valueOf(lineData[j]);
    }
}
```

### More `Maze`

`toString` should *not* be writing out to standard output!

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(this.maze2D)); // no!
    return (this.maze2D.toString());
}
```

Your `setMaze` method doesn't make much sense, as it could well disagree with the `start` and `end` fields, *hopefully* leading to a crash down-the-line, but just as likely leading to incorrect operation of the class and a meaningless result.

I also don't like `maze2D = maze2d`: it's far too easy get wrong. You are also inconsistent with your use of `this.maze2D`, which would be a better solution here.

### Accessibility

You specify `private` accessors in some places and not in others; generally it's nice to see them everywhere, because it is then unambiguous to the reader that this was the intention (as opposed to 'forgetting' the access modifier, and leaving it as the default), and is nice for people who may not use the language every-day, or may use many languages with different defaults (I, for example - coming from C# - had forgotten the default field accessibility was `package` (or whatever it is) and not `private`, which is a very important difference, e.g. in `Node`...).

### `Node`

`x`, `y`, and `parent` are not `private`: indeed, you depend on being able to access `x` and `y` from outside the class, while you provide a public getter for `parent`. I would be strongly inclined to make `Node` immutable, by making all of these fields `final`. Then you can choose whether to keep `x` and `y` as (genuinely) `public` fields, or make them `private` (like `parent` should be) and provide an appropriate getter.

I don't like the repurposing of `Node` as a `Point` or `Coordinates` structure; it's carrying around a `null` Parent everywhere, which is completely meaningless.

Why does `Node()` have a default constructor? It is never used, and doesn't look like it produces a meaningful node: I would remove it.

### Misc

- Why all the empty-lines in `Node`?
- Why are `returnStart` and `returnEnd` not called `getStart` and `getEnd`?
- Why is `results` a parameter to `printMazeResult` instead of creating it itself?
- I have no idea what `isSparse` is meant to achieve.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice I will dissect it in full soon I did fix a couple of the stuff you mentioned earlier today.

Comment: I have a problem I don't really know how to go around solving which is what isSparse is suppose to achieve because in an event I get a maze that has a section of it which is empty my code runs through the entire maze instead of taking just 1 path as a result when I print out the result every single node is printed which is useless because its not a path at all it just visits every node possible. isSparse checks if elements around a point are empty and then forces it to run down.

Comment: @MasterChiff that sounds like classic DFS; BFS won't have that problem (it will always find the optimal path), and it won't cost anything more since you are using graph search (e.g. use `Queue` instead of a `Stack` as per your comment to that effect)

Comment: I tried but when I used BFS on large mazes It would just go on for hours and I need it to resolve in seconds.

Comment: @MasterChiff if you have implemented it correctly, then the maximum run-time of a graph-search BFS and DFS should be the same (i.e. they only look at each empty cell once; you are setting the visited cell to `-1` only after expanding it, which might be creating a situation where you expand outer nodes and exponential number of times, but I've not looked at it too hard).

Comment: I see, thanks I will look into it.

Comment: thank you for your pointers I have ended up scrapping the whole thing as it was vastly over-complicated and replaced it with a greedy BFS ProrityQueue approach that works fine (still have to code the wrapping functions)